# getTimestamp is not giving the correct hour

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have this PHP code:

```
$from_date = new DateTime('April-22-2016');
$from_date->format( 'Y-m-d 00:00:00' );
$from_date->setTime(0,0,0);
print ' / '. $from_date_unix = $from_date->getTimestamp();
```

The above code prints a Unix timestamp of `1461356160`, which means 
GMT: `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 20:16:00 GMT`

The hours are `20:16:00` - which is strange, since I already set the time to `00:00:00` via

```
  $from_date->setTime(0,0,0);
```

Is my code wrong? Do I need to check something in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date you provided as first argument to [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) does not use any of the standard [date and time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) understood by PHP. Therefore, it tries to identify the date and time components in the string you provided.

A `print_r($from_date)` immediately after it was created reveals what PHP (mis-)understood from your date:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-04-22 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => -20:16
)
```

Before anything else, when it starts parsing a string for date & time, PHP initialize the new `DateTime` object with the current date, time and timezone. Then it overwrites the components it identifies in your string as follows:

- `April` was correctly identified as the month name;
- `22` is the day of the month;
- for some reason I don't know now, it set the time of the new object to `00:00:00`;
- the rest of the string (`-2016`) was used as timezone offset; i.e. `-20:16` hours.

Maybe the way it works sounds silly to you but since you provided it a random string, this is the best it could get out of it.

The next line of your code (`$from_date->format( 'Y-m-d 00:00:00' );`) produces a string and doesn't modify the `DateTime` object. Because you don't do anything with the string returned by [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), the entire line is a [`no-op`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

The next line (`$from_date->setTime(0,0,0);`) also doesn't have any effect on `$from_date` because it's time already is `00:00:00`.

Now it's clear why `$from_date->getTimestamp()` returns the time `20:16 GMT`: when it's `00:00` at the timezone with offset `-20:16`, on the GMT timezone there already is `20:16`.

---

In order to get what you want you need to use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) static function:

```
$from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    '!F-d-Y',
    'April-22-2016',
    new DateTimeZone('GMT')
);
print ' / '. $from_date_unix = $from_date->getTimestamp();
```

Remark the exclamation mark (`!`) at the start of the format specifier. It tells PHP to reset all the date and time components to the Unix Epoch. This way the generated date already has the time `00:00:00` and there is no need to set it.

Its output is:

```
1461283200
```

Comment: Really good answer - it should be the accepted one, not mine. I just came straight to the point instead of explaining everything.

Comment: Indeed, Thank you for taking the time to write such a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the DateTime object with the right format with [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Use it like this:

```
$from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!F-d-Y', 'April-22-2016');
$from_date->format( 'Y-m-d 00:00:00' );
print ' / '. $from_date_unix = $from_date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that `M` have to be `F`?

Comment: @axiac I just incorporated the change into the code of OP.

Comment: Your code outputs `1461336808` (and counting). This is not what the question asks.